# Resetting a level in unity when exiting to main menu

Tags: c#, unity, unityscript

I have a pause screen in my game having two buttons : `resume game` and `exit to main menu`
The main menu have only 1 button wish is `play`,
when i click on `exit to main menu` the main menu level is loaded,if then i click `Play` My game level scene is not restarting but continuing everything,having all it's pre created prefabs and all its game object.

How should I fix this particular bug and restarting the game when `exit to main menu` is clicked

Exit to Menu Button :

```
void OnMouseDown() {
    PauseGame.isPause=false;
    Application.LoadLevel("MainMenu");
}
```

Play button :

```
void OnMouseDown() {
    spriteRenderer.sprite = s2;
    Application.LoadLevel("Game");
}
```

[image]

[image]

I have three Prefabs:

Turret :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class Turret : MonoBehaviour {
// Use this for initialization
double LastBallTime=0.0;
double LastTurretMovingTime=0.0;
public double spawnballTime=1.5;
public double StartTurretMovingTime=35.0;
public double BallCount=2;
public bool IsRed=false;
public GameObject BallPrefab;
public GameObject RedBallPrefab;
Vector2 v ;

void Start () {
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Time.time > LastBallTime + spawnballTime) {
        LastBallTime=Time.time;
        int rand= Random.Range(1,6);
        if(rand>=1 && rand<=4)
            Instantiate(BallPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation) ;
        else{
            Instantiate(RedBallPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation) ;

        }

    }
    if (Time.time > LastTurretMovingTime + StartTurretMovingTime) {
        LastTurretMovingTime=Time.time;
        int x = Random.Range (-2,3);
        int y = Random.Range (-3,3);
        v = new Vector3 (x, y,0);
        gameObject.transform.position=v;

    }
}
void OnBecameInvisible ()
 {
    Destroy(gameObject);
 }
}
```

BALL :

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {
// Use this for initialization
public static double Killed=0;
public Text ScoreTextPrefab;
 GameObject ParentCanvas;

void Start () {
    ParentCanvas = GameObject.Find ("Canvas");
}
void OnMouseDown() {
    if (!PauseGame.isPause) {
        Text t = Instantiate (ScoreTextPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation) as Text;
        t.transform.SetParent (ParentCanvas.transform, false);
        if (gameObject.name.Contains ("RedBall")) {
                t.text = "O o P s";
                RedKilled++;
        } else {
                Killed++;       
        }
        Object.Destroy (gameObject);
    }



}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}


void OnBecameInvisible ()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
 }
}
```

TurretBall manager wish is assigned for the main camera of the game scene :

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class TurretBallManager : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization

public GameObject TurretPrefab;
public double turretSpawnTime=35;
public double LastTurretTime=0;
public double MaxTurret=10;
int currentTurretCount=1;
public Text Killedtxt;
Vector2 v;

void Start () {
    v = new Vector2(0,2);
    Instantiate (TurretPrefab, v, Quaternion.identity);

}
void CreateTurret()
{
    if (Time.time > LastTurretTime + turretSpawnTime) {
        LastTurretTime=Time.time;
        currentTurretCount++;
        if(currentTurretCount>1)
            v.x=TurretPrefab.transform.position.x-currentTurretCount/2;
        if(currentTurretCount<=MaxTurret){
            Instantiate(TurretPrefab,v,Quaternion.identity);
        }

    }
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    Killedtxt.text = "Kill : " + Ball.Killed;
    CreateTurret ();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the pause screen a new level?

Comment: no it's just a panel in the canvas

Comment: When you go to the menu, and load back the level Game, it doesn't reset? And you want it to reset?

Comment: yes exactly . i want it to reset as you enter it for the first time (like restarting the game when i go back )

Comment: There is the answer, though it might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

**Loading a level from Application.LoadLevel should rest everything unless:**

- You have set that script to DontDestroyOnLoad
- You have set some variables to be static

If it is any of those too, I would recommend manually editing the code so both should not interfere when loading from another level. In the case of the static variable, this can be done easily by setting it in the Awake Function

However, if you would simply like it to work, without editing the script in the game, there is a way. It is not the best way, but it should work fine. This does NOT work if some Game Objects are set to not Destroy on Load. They will still stay persistent. Edit the Play button script:

**OLD SCRIPT**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Play : MonoBehaviour
    {
    void OnMouseDown() 
        {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = s2;
        Application.LoadLevel("Game");
        }
    }
```

**NEW SCRIPT**

**OLD SCRIPT**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Play : MonoBehaviour
    {
    void OnMouseDown() 
        {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = s2;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
        Application.LoadLevel("Game");
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel)
        Destroy(transform.gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The issue here is that you need to set the play button to nod Destroy when loading the Game level, and then destroying it after it does that job. This is because you need it to reset the level WHEN you are accessing that level `Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel)`

Comment: but isn't you like loading the game level twice ? like hitting `f5` two times in a browser to refresh some webpage( this is an example to explain )

Comment: Exactly. That is the primary issue here. Apllication.LoadLevel SHOULD reset anything that is not a static variable or you have set to not destroy on load. Since the game does not reset when you use Apllication.LoadLevel, I am guessing is that you are using static variables. The best thing you should do is use them sparingly, so they don't have this effect. If this is not possible, this is the only way, but it is not recomended.

Comment: um actually i am using static variable for the `pause screen` and the `audioListener` but i don't know why the prefabs are still alive even after i go back and play again ,this is weird .....

Comment: Is only the prefabs still alive?

Comment: no not only the prefabs i have the timer and the score (those are static but i can reset them ) but how can i kill all the prefabs

Comment: Would it be better to instantiate a clone of the prefabs, rathen that using them specifically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20075/discussion-between-sora-and-ahkam-nihardeen).

Comment: Please check my update

Comment: Do they all not destroy on load?

Comment: yes but i found out the problem yesterday hahah it was a bit of stupid non seeing little bug and it's in the lines where i am instantiating a new turret and balls wish is : ` if (Time.time > LastTurretTime + turretSpawnTime) {
        LastTurretTime=Time.time;` i changed it to ` if (Time.timeSinceLevelLoad > LastTurretTime + turretSpawnTime) {
        LastTurretTime=Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;`

Comment: lol. I was wondering there was more to the question ;) Anyway, hope this helped you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

if you do happen to have a static variable, just initialize it again in either Awake() or Start (); then whenever you need to restart your level just call Application.loadedLevel

I was able to get it to work like this:

```
public static int aNumber;

void Awake ()
{
  int aNumberInitial = 5;
  aNumber = aNumberInitial;
}

void restartLevel () // Call this method to restart
{
  Application.loadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
}
```